# Android - How to edit specific contact group via Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, edit

I want to open system screen to edit specific group.

I guess, I need to use and Intent with ACTION_EDIT action. But, I don't know what other values I have to put in there to have a neccessary result. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: ContactsContract.Intents.  exposes actions specific to contacts and ContactsContract.Groups is another sorry I cant help more